OneSignal user-to-user push notification swift
Hi I've been following a tutorial showing how to setup push notifications using OneSignal. I've now found out the tutorial is out of date and the code samples provided no longer work. Only problem is I've looked at the API/guidance documents and I can't work it out. I also can't find any working sample code anywhere on the web.
For example my tutorial says I can send a user-to-user push notification in swift like this:
OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "Test Message"], "include_player_ids": ["3009e210-3166-11e5-bc1b-db44eb02b120"]])

Which no longer works.
I've been trying to follow the send to specific devices guidance, but am lost. Does anyone know what the up-to-date equivalent of the above code sample should be?
Probably a dum question, trying to learn how to do push notifications for the first time, maybe I shouldn't even be using OneSignal?

Chris, I think I found the answer.
OneSignal does not support the push notification with the SDK any longer.
It seems you have to use the API rest calls to send a notification now.
Here is a function I found to make it work:
func sendPushNotification(to playerId: String, message: String) {
    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Authorization": "Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY"
    ]
    
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "app_id": "YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID",
        "include_player_ids": [playerId],
        "contents": ["en": message],
        "mutable_content": true
    ]
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("Error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        return
    }
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            print("Invalid response")
            return
        }
        
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            print("Push notification sent successfully")
        } else {
            print("Error: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}

// Example usage:
sendPushNotification(to: "TARGET_PLAYER_ID", message: "Hello, this is a test notification!")

